# Assigning values to members of structures

Tags: c, structure

I am currently working on a project for a course in C programming and have run into a problem. I am still quite new to the language C but have experience programming Java.

My program runs into a problem when I try to assign a value to a **char *** variable member of a **struct**. The code in question follows below:

```
void ReadFile(ComponentType * Data, int * numEl, int * numNodes)
{
  size_t index;
  FILE * dataFile;
  char * data;
  float * value;

  numEl = malloc(sizeof(int *));
  numNodes = malloc(sizeof(int*));
  Data = malloc(6 * sizeof(ComponentType));

  * numEl = 0;
  * numNodes = 0;
  index  = 0;   

  if((dataFile = fopen("mydata.dat", "r")) == NULL)
      puts("Error - file \"mydata.dat\" could not be opened!");
  else
  { 

      while(!feof(dataFile)) 
      { 

          fscanf(dataFile, "%s", data);
          Data[index].name = (char *)malloc(strlen(data)+1);
          strcpy(Data[index].name, data);

          fscanf(dataFile, "%s", data);
          Data[index].node1 = (char *)malloc(strlen(data)+1);
          strcpy(Data[index].node1, data);

          fscanf(dataFile, "%s", data);
          Data[index].node2 = (char *)malloc(strlen(data)+1);
          strcpy(Data[index].node2, data);

          fscanf(dataFile, "%f", value);
          Data[index].value = * value;


          int i = char2int(CircuitData[index].node1);
          if(i > * numNodes)
              * numNodes = i;

          i = char2int(CircuitData[index].node2);
          if(i > * numNodes)
              * numNodes = i;

          (* numEl)++;
          (* numNodes)++;
          index++;
      }

      fclose(dataFile);
  }

  free(Data);
  free(numEl);
  free(numNodes);       
}
```

The **structure** is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
  char * name;
  char * node1;
  char * node2;
  float value;
} ComponentType;
```

I have run a debug on the program and what basically happens is that the file is read correctly and the value stored in **data** is correct however printing out **Data[index].name** either causes a segmentation fault when formatted as a **char *** or, in the debug program, prints out 0x0. In short, the values read from the file are not being copied into the structure variable I want them in.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT: I am using Linux 64-bit to code

EDIT 2: I added the entire function in which the error occurs with the changes suggested below

Comment: To answer the question properly, we need to know how data is defined and how Data.name is defined.

Comment: actually, `char * data = malloc(sizeof(char *));` is not needed. simply do `char * data;` the same is for `float` etc.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**First**: when you debug your program, check what `sizeof(data)` is.
You will be surprised to find it is 8 (the size of a pointer), and NOT 6 (the size you allocated)
This is because `sizeof` measures the size of the type, and `data` is a `char*`, (aka. a pointer).

Pointers are 8-bytes. *(on a 64-bit system. Other systems are different)*
This causes you to allocate 8 bytes for `Data[index].name`.

**Next**:  You cannot copy data from one array to another using the `=` operator, as you tried to do with:

```
Data[index].name = data;
```

---

**To do it properly**:

```
fscanf(dataFile, "%s", data);
// Measure the length of data, and allocate enough space (including the null-termiantor)
Data[index].name = malloc(strlen(data) + 1);  

// Copy from data into Data[index].name.   For greater safety, look into strcpy_s
strcpy(Data[index].name, data);
```

Comment: Ok, so I checked. A __char *__ is 8_bytes for my program and strlen(data)+1  is 3-bytes. I understand strcpy is the proper way to do it now however the __Data[index].name___ still returns 0x0

Comment: It depends how data was defined. If it was char *, yes. If it is an array the sizeof will return the size of the array. Also, strdup might be a better way of copying data to Data[index].name

Comment: To answer the question properly, you need to know how data is defined and how Data.name is defined.