# C - Assigning values to a structure with malloc isn't working

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

i'm trying to assign values to a structure using allocated memory, and i'm having some issues! I'm 4 months into programming, so sorry if i'm making a dumb mistake, but heres the code re-written for better variable names and to get rid of all the other nonsense:

```
typdef struct mystruct {
double a, b;
int c, d;}
mystruct


// allocating an array to store a number of a, b, c and d values
mystruct * pointer = ((mystruct*)malloc((numFileLines * sizeof(mystruct))));

i = 0;
pointer[i].a = 2133;
pointer[i].b = 3424; .. and so on
```

here's my problem.. I dont think these are getting stored. Does anyone see why not/How can I print these values to the console as a test?

```
i++;
pointer[i].a = 2133;
pointer[i].b = 3424;
```

This gives me garbage: (trying to print the 2nd value)

```
printf("%lf", pointer[1].b);
```

If anyone can help, or if ya need more info for this problem, I'll be refreshing this page every minute!
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning values to members of structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255964/assigning-values-to-members-of-structures)

Comment: Not quite, that individual is trying to copy one array to another. I'm just assigning a value.

Comment: After pasting your snippets into a proper program framework, cannot reproduce. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. I am using `printf("%f %f\n", pointer[1].a, pointer[1].b);`

Comment: @ Weather Vane - your printf statement, showed that it is working! awesome, thank you! I guess I have another problem..

Comment: @WeatherVane used `%f` in `printf()` while you use `%lf`. My C knowledge is getting rusty but IIRC for `double` you need `%lf`.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis you need `%lf` for `double` in `scanf` function family, in `printf` either will do. Note there is no `float` format specifier in `printf` but a `float` argument is promoted to `double`.

Comment: If your C library doesn't support C99, `%lf` in `printf` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Detail: in `scanf()`, `"%f"` matches a `float *`, `"%lf"` matches a `double *`, not a `float`, `double`.    With `printf()`, `float` arguments are promoted to `double`. In `printf()`, `"%f"` matches a `double`.  With C99+ and `printf()`, `"%lf"` works the same as `"%f"`.

Comment: Specifically, what garbage value are you seeing? You could also try re-producing your problem in a compilable form.

Comment: Your `typdef struct mystruct {...}` is incomplete and will not compile. You are missing the terminating `';'` following the ending `mystruct`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If you are gonna nitpick, you might also want to spell typedef correctly. ;-)

Comment: Hehehe, you sound like my English teacher..., If she wasn't having to wake me up, she was always reminding me that even engineers need to know how to spell `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I think why you are getting rubbish values when you are trying to print `pointer[1]` values. 
 The problem is you were using malloc() to allocate memory for your pointer which is an array. malloc() does not guarantee that memory allocation is continuous. Hence pointer[i] when i = 1 need not necessarily point to the correct memory location.
So what i would suggest is use calloc() instead of malloc(). `calloc()` ensures that memory is allocated continuously not at random places.